# Django: resolve: NoReverseMatch: 0 pattern(s) tried

Tags: django, django-views

I've tried to follow the sample here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#s-mixins-that-wrap-as-view

So here's my code:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
        print(reverse('my_home_login'))
        return login_required(view,
                              login_url=reverse('my_home_login'))

class MyHomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):
    template_name = 'my_home/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(reverse(r'my_home_login'))
        return render(request, self.template_name, {})

class MyHomeLoginView(generic.View):
    template_name = 'my_home/login.html'
```

And in my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # blabla some routes, then:
    url(_(r'^my-home$'),
        app_my_home.MyHomeView.as_view(), name='my_home_index'),
    url(_(r'^my-home/login$'),
        app_my_home.MyHomeLoginView.as_view(), name='my_home_login'),
)
```

In the log file, I can see that the `print(reverse('my_home_login'))` is called first in the `LoginRequiredMixin` (which is logical) but cant resolve the "multilinguage" route:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'my_home_login' with arguments '()'
    and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

And in my setting I've put `LocaleMiddleware` almost top:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

If I do a breakpoint in `urlresolvers.py` I see that translations are not taken in account.

If I add a route in "not translated" patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$',
        app_my_home.MyHomeLoginView.as_view(), name='login_only'),
]
```

and I try to `reverse('login_only')` in the mixin, then *it works..*. It seems that `LoginRequiredMixin` doesnt use translation urls (`i18n_patterns`). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead of `reverse` in `as_view`. The `as_view()` method runs before the urls has completely loaded, so `reverse` fails.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you very much. And why isn't there only one method instead of having reverse and reverse_lazy?

Comment: Lazy evaluation is not always required, so I assume `reverse_lazy` was added as a separate method to keep `reverse` simple.

Answer (score 0):

in urls.py you are using `MyHomeLoginView` and the name of class is `MyHomeView`.

Comment: Yes: from the view `MyHomeView` i want to use `LoginRequired` and in that mixin I want to solve `MyHomeLoginView` that's why I show all of them

Comment: can you add MyHomeLoginView as well in the question